# How to swizzle init in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, init, swizzle

I'm following [Swift & the Objective-C Runtime](http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/), it works for normal methods.

I like to swizzle init method, from my understanding, init is like a class method. So I tried swizzling init as instance and class method. But it does not seem to work

I can make it work using Objective C, just wonder how to make it work in Swift

Excerpted from my [gist](https://gist.github.com/onmyway133/2bea2d4047bdbf8ab53b)

```
dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            let originalSelector = Selector("init:source:destination:")
            let swizzledSelector = Selector("ftg_init:source:destination:")

            let originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, originalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

            let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

            if didAddMethod {
                class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
            } else {
                method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does your class inherit from? I believe swizzling only work with classes that inherit from `NSObject` or are defined as an objective c class using `@objc`.

Comment: @CleverError I linked to my gist in the question, can you take a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating the selector for a method, you should base it off the Obj C method signature since swizzling is done using the Obj C runtime.

So the original selector should be

`initWithIdentifier:source:destination:`

Now this gets a little weird, since your init method is defined so that the label on the first argument is required (by having `identifier` twice), the selector you want to use is actually

`ftg_initWithIdentifier:source:destination:`

The only [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) I could find about it talk about the translation from Obj C to Swift but it looks like the reverse is happening from Swift to Obj C.

Next, `init...` is an instance method so you'll need to make two changes. You need to change `class_getClassMethod` to `class_getInstanceMethod` and you need to remove `class` from your `ft_init...` method.

So when all is said and done, your code should look like this (which worked for me)

```
dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
    let originalSelector = Selector("initWithIdentifier:source:destination:")
    let swizzledSelector = Selector("ftg_initWithIdentifier:source:destination:")

    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

    let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

    if didAddMethod {
        class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    }
}

func ftg_init(identifier identifier: String!,
    source: UIViewController,
    destination: UIViewController) -> UIStoryboardSegue {

    return ftg_init(identifier: identifier,
        source: source,
        destination: destination.ftg_resolve())
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the way of doing it in Swift 4.2 for UIImage initializer:

```
@objc static func ftg_imageNamed(_ name: String) -> UIImage? {
    ...
}

private static func swizzleInitImplementation() {
    let originalSelector = #selector(UIImage.init(named:))
    let swizzledSelector = #selector(UIImage.ftg_imageNamed(_:))

    guard let originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, originalSelector), let swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, swizzledSelector) else {
        assertionFailure("The methods are not found!")
        return
    }

    let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))
    if didAddMethod {
        class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    }
}
```

Comment: I voted this up cause I couldn't figure out `#selector(UIImage.init(named:))` until your post.  Thank you!  One thing: `Static methods may only be declared on a type` is what I'm getting at global scope.

Comment: Also, I'm having trouble casting self to AnyClass as is required by these methods if these methods are supposed to live in a `uiimage` extension...