# How to swizzle init method of NSURLConnection class

Tags: ios, swift, swizzling, method-swizzling

I want to swizzle init init method of NSURLConnection class and i have tried this code but it doesn't seem to work for me

```
extension NSURLConnection{
public override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        let originalSelector = Selector("init:delegate:startImmediately:")
        let swizzledSelector = Selector("my_init:delegate:startImmediately:")

        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

        let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

        if didAddMethod {
            class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Method Swizzling
func my_init(request: NSURLRequest, delegate: AnyObject?, startImmediately: Bool){
 print("Inside Swizzled Method")
}
}
```

And here is the request which i am initiating from my view controller

```
let testPoint: String = "www.google.com"
    guard let url = NSURL(string: testPoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let conn = NSURLConnection(request: urlRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
```

Comment: you don't swizzle selectors... you swizzle method IMPs. use class_replaceMethod. use the same selector.

Comment: Just noticed it after I posted an answer: `class_replaceMethod(NSURLSession.self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))`
`NSURLSession`?

Comment: i have edited my question @yoninja

Comment: @ManuGupta, corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension NSURLConnection{
public override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    if self !== NSURLConnection.self {
        return
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        let originalSelector = Selector("initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:")
        let swizzledSelector = Selector("initWithTest:delegate:startImmediately:")

        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

        let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

        if didAddMethod {
            class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Method Swizzling
convenience init(test: NSURLRequest, delegate: AnyObject?, startImmediately: Bool){
    print("Inside Swizzled Method")
    self.init()
}
}
```

Comment: i have tried like you have told but still no luck for me

Comment: and in the same can we swizzle sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: ?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: By the way @ManuGupta , if you don't mind, if it solved your problem then it is fitting to accept it as the right answer.

Comment: oops my bad i up voted it but forget to accept as right answer

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things that have to be fixed:

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323664/2128900), you should use Objective-C method signature in `originalSelector`:

```
`let originalSelector = Selector("initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:")`
```

You don't return anything from `my_init` method. You should return the same type as the method being swizzled, in this case `NSURLConnection`.

```
func my_init(request: NSURLRequest, delegate: AnyObject?, startImmediately: Bool) -> NSURLConnection? {
    print("Inside Swizzled Method")
    //call the original initializer
    return my_init( request, delegate: delegate, startImmediately: startImmediately)
}
```

You can see that `my_init` is called in the swizzled method. In the runtime, it will call the original `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately` as the methods will have been already swapped at this point.

Last but not least, `NSURLConnection` is deprecated in iOS 9. It is highly recommended to use `NSURLSession` instead, as it's more modern and has more useful features.

Comment: True! NSURLConnection is deprecated. If there's no reason to use it then drop it and use NSURLSession.