# How to create a common function in UIViewcontroller extenstion?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I need to run the common function to all UIViewcontroller without manually specifying "self.function()"

Comment: When do you want it to run?

Comment: automatically need run for each UIviewcontroller did load. but won't specify function name.

Comment: Create BaseViewController of type UIViewController, override all the behavior needed. Then create all the rest of your vcs as subclasses of BaseViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible to swizzle the viewDidload() in swift4 although it is possible earlier by swizzling, instead you can do it by inheritance

```
Class BaseVC: UIViewController {
    func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
  /// customization here … e.g self.function() 
    }
}

Class CustomVC: BaseVC {
 func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
     // you had called self.function no need to do it again 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Leena had u got the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just add your custom methods to the UIViewController using extension:

```
extension UIViewController {

   func customFunc() {
      print("Custom func is called")
   }
}
```

Now, inside every class that inherits from UIViewController you can easily access this func:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   //call your func
   customFunc()
   }

}
```

Comment: I guess I got the downvote because the OP asked not to call the function manually but run it automatically at the viewDidLoad(). Fair enough. Most probably I didn't notice this one detail at the time of writing the solution. Oops.

Answer (score -3):

The only way to override a function in a class you cannot modify (such as the `UIViewController` base class) is to use method swizzling.

[How to swizzle init in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317766/how-to-swizzle-init-in-swift#34323664)

You an use this technique to swizzle `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`.

Most of the time though, you should just subclass the `UIViewController` for your needs and call your function in the lifecycle method override.